# Disable start and end animation from ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I disable the blue color when reaching the end of a ListView in Xamarin Forms?
If it is not possible to disable this, is there a way to change the Color to transparent?

My ListView:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW1Ts.jpg

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you can change the `OverScrollMode` for your `ListView` either with a custom renderer or an effect. If you want to do it throughout the entire app I'd use a renderer, but if you only want to do it with one specific listview or only a couple I would use an effect. Here is an example of how to do it with an effect.

In your Forms project create the effect:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourApp.Effects
{
    public class ListViewEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public ListViewEffect() : base("YourApp.ListViewEffect") { }
    }
}
```

Then in your Android project:

```
using YourApp.Droid.Effects;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("YourApp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(ListViewEffect), "ListViewEffect")]
namespace YourApp.Droid.Effects
{
    public class ListViewEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Control.OverScrollMode = Android.Views.OverScrollMode.Never;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached() { }
    }
}
```

Then you have to add the effect to your `ListView` in Forms

```
in xaml

xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:YourApp.Effects"

<ListView>
    <ListView.Effects>
        <effects:ListViewEffect/>
    </ListView.Effects>
    ...
</ListView>

or in the CS file

_listView.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve("YourApp.ListViewEffect"));
```

For more info you can check out the docs [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) and [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating)

Answer (score 0):

I believe these values are not control by WF but rather the platform specific settings. For example; Navigate to the Android project and locate the Resources>Values>Styles.xml
The theme controls the colours and there are values for the theme colours for Primary, Dark and accent. I dont think it's possible to change these values to transparent but themes are a good place to start looking.